# .NET MongoDB Bad Projection Specification

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm in the process of upgrading a system from the Legacy Mongo Drivers to the new ones.  I've got an issue with the following query.

```
        var orgsUnitReadModels = _readModelService.Queryable<OrganisationalUnitReadModel>()
            .Where(x => locations.Contains(x.Id))
            .Select(x => new AuditLocationItemViewModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                AuditRecordId = auditRecordId,
                Type = type,
                IsArchived = !x.IsVisible,
                AuditStatus = auditStatus
            }).ToList();
```

It produces the following error message, which I don't understand.  I would be grateful for assistance explaining what this means and how to fix it.

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: Bad
> projection specification, cannot exclude fields other than '_id' in an
> inclusion projection: { Id: "$_id", Name: "$Name", AuditRecordId:
> BinData(3, 5797FCCCA90C8644B4CB84FED4236D4B), Type: 0, IsArchived: {
> $not: [ "$IsVisible" ] }, AuditStatus: 2, _id: 0 }.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example LINQ's Select statement gets translated into MongoDB's [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Typically you use `0` (or `false`) to exclude fields and `1` or `true` to include fields in a final result set. Of course you can also use the dollar syntax to refer to existing fields which happens for instance for `Name`.

The problem is that you're also trying to include some in-memory constant values as part of the projection. Unfortunately one of them (`type`) is equal to `0` which is interpreted as if you would like to exclude a field called `Type` from the pipeline result.

Due to this ambiguity MongoDB introduced [$literal](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/index.html) operator and you can try following syntax in Mongo shell:

```
db.col.aggregate([{ $project: { _id: 0, Id: 1, Name: 1, Type: { $literal: 0 } } }])
```

It will return `0` as a constant value as you expect. The MongoDB .NET driver documentation mentions literal [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/expressions/) but it looks like it only works for strings.

There's a couple of ways you can solve your problem, I think the easier is to run simpler `.Select` statement first and then use `.ToList()` to make sure the query is materialized. Once it's done you can run another in-memory `.Select()` to build your `OrganisationalUnitReadModel`:

```
.Where(x => locations.Contains(x.Id))
.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.IsVisible }).ToList()
.Select(x => new AuditLocationItemViewModel
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    Type = type,
    IsArchived = !x.IsVisible,
    AuditStatus = auditStatus
}).ToList();
```